# Troubles with running django app via wsgi on ubuntu 17

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I need your help.
I have an error when trying to run on wsgi my django project.
I'm using Ubuntu 17, Apache2, Django 2.0, Python 3.6

When I running from manage.py, everything is working, but when via wsgi got the next error :

> AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/cardsite/cardsite/: No matching
>   DirectoryIndex
>   (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found,
>   and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

And don't know why, because I guess set everything correct. Bellow my configuration :

apache.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/cardsite-access.log common
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/cardsite-error.log
DocumentRoot /var/cardsite/cardsite/
Alias /static /var/cardsite/cardsite/static/
<Directory /var/cardsite/cardsite/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/cardsite/cardsite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
WSGIDaemonProcess cardsite python-path=/var/cardsite/ python-home=/var/venv_python36/
WSGIProcessGroup cardsite
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/cardsite/cardsite/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
PROJECT_DIR = '/var/cardsite'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cardsite.settings")
def execfile(filename):
     globals = dict( __file__ = filename )
     exec( open(filename).read(), globals )

activate_this = os.path.join( '/var/venv_python36/bin', 'activate_this.py' )
execfile( activate_this )
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

P.S. Permissions I have give on folder and all which inside.
P.S.S. Packages like "libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3" or "mod-wsgi" via pip3 also installed.

Thank you all for the any suggestion what's it can be

Answer (score 3):

Don't set `DocumentRoot` to be a parent directory of your source code. If you were to take the `WSGIScriptAlias` out, people could download your source code. You should avoid the risk of that, even if `WSGIScriptAlias` currently intercepts everything under `/`. That `DocumentRoot` directory doesn't allow access may be part of the problem also.

Try:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/cardsite-access.log common
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/cardsite-error.log

DocumentRoot /var/cardsite/htdocs

<Directory /var/cardsite/htdocs>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /static /var/cardsite/cardsite/static

<Directory /var/cardsite/cardsite/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

WSGIDaemonProcess cardsite python-path=/var/cardsite python-home=/var/venv_python36

WSGIProcessGroup cardsite
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/cardsite/cardsite/wsgi.py

<Directory /var/cardsite/cardsite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The `WSGIApplicationGroup` has been added as always a good idea to have that, with only one WSGI application delegated to the daemon process group.

Make sure you create the directory:

```
/var/cardsite/htdocs
```

Finally, you are missing a `ServerName` directive. So if this isn't the default `VirtualHost`, your request may not even be getting handled by this `VirtualHost`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I made these changes, but unfortunately error still there.. :(

Comment: Do you have any other ``VirtualHost`` defined? As I said, this one will not be used if you do as ``ServerName`` isn't set.

Comment: Also try commenting out the ``mod_rewrite`` rules to eliminate them as being the problem.